# Do operations that contain bit-wise AND (&) or bit-wise exclusive OR(^) have a decimal equivalent?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Consider the following expressions in which both operand are decimal : `a^b`   or `a&b`

I know what the operators do on binary digits of operands and hence i know how the answer 
of `a^b` or `a&b` is calculated.
What I do not know is  if those  operations can be translated to decimal form

for example : we can say that `a<<b` is equivalent to this operation :`a*pow(2,n)`

Is `a^b` or `a&b` equivalent to anything like that??

Comment: Nope. There *is* something like that for the bitwise complement though: `~x == -x - 1`

Answer (score 2):

Bit operations (AND, OR, NOT, XOR) are logical extensions of Boolean algebra. Boolean algebra operates on binary values (true/false if you want). So no, there is no extension to decimal values, for this operators.

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no "decimal" equivalent.

First of all, integers are integers ... not binary integers or decimal integers.

Second, the `^`, `&` and `|` operators are defined (mathematically) in terms of their. effect on individual bits, so it is not even clear what a decimal equivalent might be.

> For example : we can say that `a<<b` is equivalent to this operation: `a*pow(2,n).` Is `a^b` or `a&b` equivalent to anything like that??

In a word ... no.

(And besides, the example you have is nothing to do with binary versus decimal.)

---

The only thing I can think of that *could* be construed as the decimal equivalent of something like this:

1. Convert the two `int` operands into arrays of integers, where each element of each array represents a decimal digit in the corresponding `int`.
2. Perform a bitwise operation on the corresponding elements of each `int` array giving a 3rd `int` array.
3. Turn the 3rd `int` array back into an `int`.

(Or you could do the same using strings rather than integer arrays ...)

However, it is not clear to me that this is either meaningful or ... what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

No. The closest thing one could probably get without becoming to far-fetched is to *compare* them to decimal operators:

- The `&` operator could be compared to multiplication (`0*0=0`, `0*1=0`, `1*1=1`)
- The `^` operator could be compared to carry-less addition (`0+0=0`, `0+1=1`, `1+1=0`)
- The `|` operator could be compared to regular addition (`0+0=0`, `0+1=1`, `1+1=2`)

However, these comparisons obviously break down when applied to anything other than 0 or 1.

Comment: @harold: Derp, yes. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can rewrite *any boolean operation* in terms of **NOT, OR, AND** only, e.g.

```
  a XOR b = (a AND (NOT b)) OR ((NOT a) AND b)  
  a EQU b = (a AND b) OR ((NOT a) AND (NOT b))  
  a IMP b = (NOT a) OR b
```

etc. In *partial case* when **a** and **b** are **bits** (a is equal either to 0 or to 1
and so does b) you *can* put simple arithemtic equivalents for the operations:

```
    NOT a == 1 - a
  a AND b == a * b
   a OR b == a + b - a * b 
  (for XOR, see the formula above and put expressions for AND, NOT and OR)
```

In *general* case, however, logical operations (**NOT, OR, AND**) are performed
*on number's bits* that's why there're *no simple decimal equivalents* for
these operations

Answer (score 0):

The bit XOR operation `a^b` is like an addition without the carry.
The bit AND operation `a&b` is like computing presence of a carry.
Thus, you can get this not so useful relation `(a^b) + ((a&b)<<1) == (a+b)`
Not so useful because it transforms an addition into another more complex addition.
It's more useful when proceeding bit after bit.

Note that if you repeat this transformation on resulting operands `a_2=(a_1^b_1)` and `b_2=(a_1&b_1)<<1` enough times (until `b_n==0`) then you'll get the result of the addition in `a_n`.